# I delete dimension .xml file from android studio and after creating a new one i have No resource found error so what should i do?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio

What if i delete dimension file from android studio and after creating anew one i have the error at the image.

[image]

The Error is  No resource found that matches the given name (at `android:layout_height` with value `@dimen/list_item_height`).

How should i create anew dimension file from zero to solve this problem?

Comment: Can you add you new file content here. Are you sure you have  list_item_height in there

Comment: If you accidentally deleted the dimens file,  Follow these steps, Right click on `res` folder and click in `Show History`. You can recover your past changes from here

Answer (score 0):

For create new dimension file go to **Project -> app -> src -> main -> res** then right click on values folder then **New -> Values resource file** and assign name **dimens**.

After that create value inside file e.g. **list_item_height**.

Answer (score 0):

dimension file has tagged list_item_height.

you need create this tag in new file dimension or remove tag in xml file in layout.